# Why the value will not add or minus when the button clicked

Tags: javascript

Why the number will not change when the button is clicked?

function cartElement($productimg, $productname, $productprice, $productid){
$element = "

```
<form action=\"cart.php?action=remove&id=$productid\" method=\"post\" class=\"cart-items\">
                <div class=\"border rounded\">
                    <div class=\"row bg-white\">
                        <div class=\"col-md-3 pl-0\">
                            <img src=$productimg alt=\"Image1\" class=\"img-fluid\">
                        </div>
                        <div class=\"col-md-6\">
                            <h5 class=\"pt-2\">$productname</h5>
                            <small class=\"text-secondary\">Seller: dailytuition</small>
                            <h5 class=\"pt-2\">$$productprice</h5>
                            <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-warning\">Save for Later</button>
                            <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-danger mx-2\" name=\"remove\">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class=\"col-md-3 py-5\">
                            <div>
                                <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"add()\" class=\"btn bg-light border rounded-circle\" value=\"increment\"><i class=\"fas fa-minus\"></i></button>
                                <input type=\"text\" value=\"1\" class=\"form-control w-25 d-inline\">
                                <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"minus()\" class=\"btn bg-light border rounded-circle\" value=\"decrement\"><i class=\"fas fa-plus\"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
var x=0

var element = document.getElementById(\"value\");
element.innerHTML = x;

function add(){
    element.innerHTML = ++x;
}
function minus(){
    element.innerHTML = --x;
}
```

Comment: You call `document.getElementById("value")`, but you do not have an element with an ID of `value`. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I made some change, are you want something like this ?

```js
    var x=0;
    
    var element = document.getElementById("value");
    
    
    function add(){
        ++x; 
        element.value=x;
   }
    function minus(){
        --x; 
        element.value=x;
    }
```

```html
<input id="value" value="0"  />

<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<button onclick="minus()">Minus</button>
```